# SqlDataAdapter returns empty data set

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I have a question. I've tried to solve it all day long and I am really stuck. I'm using VS2010 and SQL Server 2012 (quite a bad combination) and I'm trying to execute a fairly simple piece of C# and ASP.net code which goes like this:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BazaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn);

SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  Seminar", connect);
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataTable tablica = new DataTable();
sqlAdapter.Fill(tablica);

GridView1.DataSource = tablica;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The problem is my gridview is always empty. I have data in the table and `SELECT *` should select all of it but I get an empty table returned. I've been trying Dataset and DataTable but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you're sure that (1) your connection string is correct, (2) your `SELECT` statement really returns values, and (3) you're not getting any exception in the process that you're just swallowing and ignoring??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that you might be running into an exception - possibly a timeout - and you're not dealing with this properly...

Try something like this:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BazaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  Seminar", connect))
using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
   try
   {
      DataTable tablica = new DataTable();
      sqlAdapter.Fill(tablica);

      GridView1.DataSource = tablica;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
       string msg = exc.GetType().FullName + ": " + exc.Message;
   }
}
```

If you execute this code - do you happen to fall into the `catch` block? If so: what's the exception? What does it tell you?

Comment: No exceptions :S The connection string is okay. It connects to correct table. If i put for example name of a column that is in the table it displays nothing, but if i put name of non existing column i get error that column isn't there so it seems to be looking the correct DB and Table, but why it sees nothing in it, that is what i don't know :S

Comment: @user1692436: and if you do a `int rowCount = tablica.Rows.Count;` right after filling the `DataTable` - do you have rows in the resulting `DataTable`? If yes: then there's something wrong with your grid, most likely (does it have fixed column definitions that might not be matching any of the columns returned in your `DataTable`?)

Comment: The problem seems to be the gridview my row count was 4, and now i deleted the gridview and put in a new one and it works indeed. before i put drag and drop datasource and the grid view seems to have taken some settings from there. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn);
connect.Open();
```

Comment: No, that's not needed - the `SqlDataAdapter` will open (and close) the connection as needed.